# cmus doesn't add m4a files

Tags: 14.10, m4a, cmus

I am using cmus 2.6 (built from source, as the version in the repository was giving segfault on adding music), and it just doesn't detect m4a tracks.

I checked the plugins, and the aac plugin is indeed installed. I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Is this still an issue in 16.04?

Answer (score 1):

I'm here in 2019 with an answer! Kinda. Idk about compiling from source, but using the package manager:

Install the cmus-plugin-ffmpeg package to add m4a support, among others

Comment: I don't use CMUS anymore so can't say, but hopefully this helps someone else!